# Best way to keep track of users and records in a NET Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build an Inventory web application with .NET Core. In this app, I want to keep track of every create and update operation, so almost every model in my application has CreatedBy and ModifiedBy fields and each of those fields have a one-to-many relationship with the UserId field from the Users model.

So there are a lot of foreign keys in my models and lots of navigational properties in my Users model. It works but looks kind of messy especially in my Users model so it got me thinking maybe there is something wrong with my approach. I thought of some other ways but I am just learning the ropes so I can't really predict the possible downsides of those approaches, thus, I need help.

So what's the best way to deal with this kind of situation in a web application?

Should I keep defining foreign keys?

Should I store UserId as string in those columns?

Should I create another table which holds records for every create / update operation?

Is there a better way out there?

Comment: Do you have some other issues with your current approach other than "looks kind of messy"? If no, then do what you did so far until it will introduce actual issues (performance, maintainability, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I decided to go on with temporal tables solution from SQL Server directly. You have to add just a couple of codes to your dbcontext's onmodelcreating method to set it up and it looks like it's working very good for my needs.